# Steam Fails to Load

Tags: steam

I've tried installing from several different sources and by several different ways. I always get the same outcome

```
:/usr/share$ steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 14.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1416617579)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1416617579)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1416617579)
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(20141121162341)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(1416587021)
[1231/124906:ERROR:nss_util.cc(1018)] Failed to load NSS libraries.
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(20141121162341)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(1416587021)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(1416587021)
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 78: saw unknown, expected number
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1416617579)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1416617579)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1416617579)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1416617579)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1416617579)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1416617579)
FillInMachineIDInfo took a total of 0 milliseconds
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1416617579)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1416617579)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1416617579)
Generating new string page texture 2: 48x256, total string texture memory is 49.15 KB
Generating new string page texture 3: 384x256, total string texture memory is 442.37 KB
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1416617579)
local (potentially out of sync) copy of roaming config loaded - 0 bytes.
Generating new string page texture 4: 256x256, total string texture memory is 704.51 KB
Adding licenses for the following package(s): 0
roaming config store loaded successfully - 0 bytes.
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1416617579)
Failed to init SteamVR because it isn't installed
ExecCommandLine: ""/home/richardveevers/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam" "
System startup time: 14.40 seconds
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1416617579)
[1231/124920:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(227)] Running without renderer sandbox
Uploading dump (out-of-process) [proxy '']
/tmp/dumps/assert_20141231124904_1.dmp
Running Steam on ubuntu 14.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME has been set by the user to: /home/richardveevers/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime
/home/richardveevers/.steam/steam.sh: line 729:  4758 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) $STEAM_DEBUGGER "$STEAMROOT/$STEAMEXEPATH" "$@"
Requested Force create but SharedObjectMutex already created
Forced create but already created for SharedObjectEvent
Forced create but already created for SharedObjectEvent
```

Can log into Steam account, then nothing.

Running 
ubuntu 14.04 LTS 
AMD Athlon 64
Gallium 0.4 on NV44

```
lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS480/RS482/RS485 Host Bridge (rev 10)
00:02.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS4xx PCI Express Port [ext gfx]
00:07.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RC4xx/RS4xx PCI Express Port 4
00:12.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB600 Non-Raid-5 SATA
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB600 USB (OHCI0)
00:13.1 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB600 USB (OHCI1)
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB600 USB (OHCI2)
00:13.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB600 USB (OHCI3)
00:13.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB600 USB (OHCI4)
00:13.5 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB600 USB Controller (EHCI)
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 SMBus Controller (rev 13)
00:14.1 IDE interface: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB600 IDE
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB600 PCI to LPC Bridge
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] HyperTransport Technology Configuration
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Address Map
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] DRAM Controller
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Miscellaneous Control
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation NV44 [Quadro NVS 285] (rev a1)
3f:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5755 Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express (rev 02)
```

More details
    Package ia32-libs is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0

E: Package 'ia32-libs' has no installation candidate